# how change navbar height without corrupt collapse nave mode?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have nave with 40px height and I change some css property to achive this but after that when I resize window my navbar not work good in collapse mode

css that I changed:

```
.navbar {
    border-radius:0;
    height:40px !important;
    margin-bottom:20px; 
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;    
}
.navbar-brand {
    height:40px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find the question in here. Perhaps an example of what it should look like and what it currently looks like will help.